# Create properties on Neo4j list that might be null

Tags: neo4j

I have a csv file with email data like:

```
Id,To,CC
0,a@z.com,b@z.com
1,,
2,a@z.com;b@z.com;c@z.com,d@z.com;e@z.com
```

The `To` and `CC` fields can contain zero or more addresses, with addresses split by `;`'s. What I would like to do is create nodes representing emails by `Id` and nodes representing `Entity`'s with `[:TO]` relationships (and I'd eventually like to add a `CarobonCopied` property to the relationship when it was a CC). There are a lot of other things going on in the file too, but this is the corner I'm stuck on.

I am doing the following to create the nodes, and this works (I am new to Neo4j, so I don't know if it is elegant though):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///short_FieldCleanedEmails.csv' AS line
WITH line,
SPLIT(line.To, ';') AS tos,
SPLIT(line.CC, ';') AS ccs

// loop over to's
FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(line.From) <> ""
         THEN [1] ELSE [] END | FOREACH (addr in tos |
         MERGE (entity_to:Entity {NameAddress: addr})))
// loop over cc's
FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(line.CC) <> ""
         THEN [1] ELSE [] END | FOREACH (addr in ccs |
         MERGE (entity_cc:Entity {NameAddress: addr})))
;
```

But what I can't figure out is how to make the relationships. I want to do something like nested `FOREACH` calls, but that doesn't work.

I am trying this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///short_FieldCleanedEmails.csv' AS line
WITH line,
SPLIT(line.To, ';') AS tos,
SPLIT(line.CC, ';') AS ccs

MATCH (email:Email {id: TOINT(line.Id)})
// loop over to's
FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(line.From) <> ""
         THEN [1] ELSE [] END | FOREACH (addr in tos |
         MATCH (entity_to:Entity {NameAddress: addr}),
         CREATE (email)-[:TO]->(entity_to)))
// loop over cc's
FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(line.CC) <> ""
         THEN [1] ELSE [] END | FOREACH (addr in ccs |
         MATCH (entity_cc:Entity {NameAddress: addr}),
         CREATE (email)-[t:TO]->(entity_cc)))
;
```

and it is not working because it is illegal to nest `FOREACH` statements I guess.(I created the Email nodes previously, and here I haven't gotten to the step of adding the `CarbonCopy` property to the `[:TO]`'s for CC's.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` instead of the outer `FOREACH`.

```
FOREACH (addr IN FILTER(addr IN tos WHERE addr <> "")|
    MERGE (entity_to:Entity {NameAddress: addr} )
    MERGE (email) - [:TO] -> (entity_to))
```

Or use `UNWIND` and filter notation instead, it's a little cleaner (especially if you're used to list comprehensions):

```
UNWIND [x IN tos WHERE x <> ""] AS addr
MERGE (entity_to:Entity {NameAddress: addr} )
MERGE (email) - [:TO] -> (entity_to)
```

You also want to `MERGE` the `entity_to` node, because the query will throw an error when creating the relationship if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: To clarify: When `line.To` is a blank string, the result of `SPLIT(line.To, ';')` is a single-item list `['']` containing one empty string. Applying the filter (using filter or filter notation) results in an _actually_ empty list, which either `UNWIND` or `FOREACH` will handle as expected.